# PostMapping with Parameters from URI

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to build a spring boot @PostMapping method that gets it's parameters from the uri, something like this
http://localhost:8091/url/log?param1=asdf&param2=asd&param3=test
or like this
http://localhost:8091/url/log/msg/msg1/msg2

Is there a way to expand the code model from below to 3 parameters? 
headers.setLocation(builder.path("/article/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}")

```
@PostMapping("article")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> addArticle(@RequestBody ArticleInfo articleInfo, UriComponentsBuilder builder) {
        Article article = new Article();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(articleInfo, article);


            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setLocation(builder.path("/article/{id}").buildAndExpand(article.getArticleId()).toUri());
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Comment: First: Your post calls should have request params. `http://localhost:8091/url/log?param1=asdf&param2=asd&param3=test` is a bad way of doing it.

Second: `http://localhost:8091/url/log/msg/msg1/msg2` is a good approach

The Better approach would be to create a Request json object

Comment: The problem was I didnt use @Autowired before the ArticleRepository :(

Comment: I will use Sovannarith method now, im so dumb.
Maybe it will help other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to expand the code model from below to 3 parameters? headers.setLocation(builder.path("/article/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}")

You can use [@PathVariable](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html), like below

```
@PostMapping("article/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}")
public ResponseEntity<Void> addArticle(@PathVariable("param1") String param1, @PathVariable("param3") String param3, @PathVariable("param3") String param3) {
    //enter code here
}
```

Comment: Your params are mostly used for get calls. You never want to expose the data in an url which you want to save

Comment: @NaveenKulkarni I just give what he want !! :(

Comment: The forum here is not only to give what he / she wants. Its also to correct them if they are doing it in the wrong way.

Answer (score 4):

If you simply want your API call to create a new Article, how about simply having a `PostMapping` to `/article/new` (for example) and then simply pass the new Article's parameters as RequestBody?

```
@PostMapping("article/new")
public ResponseEntity<Void> addArticle(@RequestBody Article article) {
// ...
}
```

Then as RequestBody you would have something like:

```
{ "param1": "value1", "param2": "value2", "param3": "value3" }
```

If you're just looking to include more PathVariable's to your api call, refer to @sovannarith cheav's answer

I hope this helps

Comment: If the params in the RequestBody are correct, they are mapped automatically to the Article object, therefore just add your own logic to save the article object. I would use a service with a save method, for example: articlesService.save(article);